# Client -> server time differences and time storage

Tags: mysql, timezone, client-server

I'm developing a client app that when the user reads something, I "save" it to the DB including the time and date. At first I thought of using NOW() (mysql) and let the server/db do the hard work but then I realized there is a difference between the server time and client time.

To overcome this, whenever I call the API that stores this info in the DB, I pass the client date time as one of the parameters. No big deal ofcourse, I was just wondering, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control on the server ?

You can't make sure that the client's date/time will be correct, so use the server time instead (Even if it is correct at a given point it might change and will give you inconsistent results).

The only valid reason for the server and the client time to be different is that they are on a different timezones (if they differ for another reason, it's the client's problem, not yours).

The solution is to store the client timezone on the server along with the time as UTC (timestamp) and let the database or your scripts do the translation to show the correct date/time to the client.

I don't know well the mysql way of handling date/time values but it appears that you can't automatically store the timezone along with the time value so you will have to do it manually:

- Create a timezone column attached to each client.
- Whenever you store a date/time in mysql convert it from you server timezone to UTC : GMT+0 (Mysql might do that automatically).
- Whenever a client retrieve a date/time: get the UTC time and the timezone, and convert it (this can be done either on client's side, or server side).

Most web languages have standard ways of managing date/time and timezones.

You also can set the mysql session timezone as shown here : [mysql timestamp tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx) but i think the first solution is more flexible and not mysql-dependent.

I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: the problem is timezone. If the user read it at 2pm, the db will store it as 5pm (for example) so you say I should store the user timezone so whenever I fetch this info to the user, I will translate it back to his timezone? Is there a more automated way for this? you wrote something about UTC, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: After your update: the problem with this is divided in to 2: the first which is less possible is when the client moves to a different timezone and the second which is more possible is that the MYSQL DB will move to a different server which means a different timezone so all the timezones I kept will be irrelevant

Comment: That is why you have to store the date/time as UTC. That way it will always be consistent. If your server moves to another timezone: it does not matter, everythin is stored as UTC. If a client moves to a different timezone: there are several ways to manage that depending on you needs: let the user change its TZ configuration for all records and every date/time will be adjusted with the new one or add a timezone history.