# Finding the difference between client time and server time

Tags: python, asp.net, spring, timezone, client-server

I have a server that stores events happening in different parts of the world. They all save UNIX timestamps of the time when the event will occur and end.

At the same time I have a script that queries the database and compares the server time minus the end time of the event.

If the result of the comparison is greater than, or equal to 0. Then it means that the event already occurred and should be removed from the database.

But **my problem is that:**
If an event is created in UK (GMT+1) and set to end at 7:00 PM, and the server being in Germany (GMT+2).  The event will be deleted an hour earlier, that is: 6:00 PM in the UK and 7:00 PM in Germany.

**What I want is that:**
If the created event ends at 7:00 PM in UK, it should be deleted at 8:00 PM in Germany.

I've look around for a solution but I'm not sure [if this would be the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28679278/7770585)?

Comment: Do you know the time zone of the server?

Where will the script that queries be executed?

Comment: yea, sounds like using UTC, like in the article is the correct solution for you

Comment: @gelonida The time zone of the server is GMT+2 in Germany/Frankfurt.

Comment: unix time stamps are universal. If you get the server time in UTC you should be able to compare it the same way independent of the location you're executing the script from

Comment: @gelonida No, 1590714479 this is timestime in Germany, and this: 1590718079 is in Romania, there is a difference of 3600 seconds, so 1 hour. UTC is different for every timezone

Comment: @GicuMironica

I'm at a loss:
https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ states " This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC". So a unix time stamp should be identical for the same time in Germany and Romania of course it would for example be 8pm (UTC+2), in Germany  and 9pm in Romania ( UTC+3) , but this is the ***same*** time.

Perhaps you and I define the word `same` in a different manner?

The page states further *that this point in time technically does not change no matter where you are located on the globe*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got the question right.

In the data base you store unix time stamps,

Then why don't you compare the unix time stamps from the data base with the current unix time stamp to decide which entry should be deleted.

In python you get the current time stamp with

`time.time()`

So something like that should work:

```
import time

now = time.time()
query = "select primarykey, timestamp from table"
for primary_key, timestamp in yourfuncttoexecutequeryandreturnrows(query):
    if timestamp < now:
        print("I could delete entry ", primary_key)
```